# Ubuntu doesn't render the window boundaries and top left corner correctly after sleep

Tags: suspend

Really I have no idea how this happened or how to describe it correctly.

I think it started after a `sudo apt upgrade`, and every time I close the lid on my laptop and re-open the lid, this happens.

[image: The re-rendered windows]